# Adding, deleting and editing users by admin in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website using php and I created the login and sign up processes successfully. Now, I am working in the admin page and I want to let him adding, deleting users and editing the personal information of the existed users. I heard there are some ready php applications for that which can be integrated with any web application.

I googled about them but up to now I did not find anyone that does what I want.

Also, if the user wants to retrieve his personal information from the database, will that be affected by using those ready systems.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try out CakePHP http://cakephp.org/ . It is a rapid PHP development template that has tons of features including login system but it requires a certain level of pre-PHP development knowledge.