# How to retrieve users information from the database for admin in php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding, deleting and editing users by admin in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080562/adding-deleting-and-editing-users-by-admin-in-php)

Hello,

I am new in developing the website by php and I am trying to learn it by creating a simple website which mainly consists of two parts:
1. sign up, login and the website information (as the visitor part)
2. adding, deleting and editing user information (as the admin part)

I created the sign up and login and now I am working in the admin part of the website.
I made the adding users as sign up process, but now I am facing problem with deleting and editing the users. What I want is to list all users in the database in the admin page so he can select either to delete the user or to edit his information, so how can I do that?

I tried a lot to retrieve the users from the database but I failed. I know guys this task maybe simple but excuse me because I am new to this field.

FYI, I am using XAMPP package and Notepad.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: Stop using notepad, it only makes things harder. Try a programmer's editor instead, such as [EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/), or an IDE such as [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/).

Comment: Another good choice is Notepad++ on Windows http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: On linux, try geany, or even vim.

Comment: There are lots of programmers' editors and IDEs. It was just a side note :) Let's not get into it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a crude and working solution, I suggest putting everything (logic, view etc) into a single file like below.

You'd probably want to separate the logic (input checks, form processing etc) from the view (outputting the edit form, result etc), obviously the variant below is "dirty" in this scope.

Note that i didn't actually run this, so there may be some missed brackets or something, and most of the code is absent - there are many 'todo'-style comments there. Just as a possible example, hopefully of use to you.

```
<?php

// default page view is list users
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'list';

switch ($action) {

 case 'list': 
  // just query for all users and output edit & delete links
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name /* and anything else needed */ FROM users ORDER BY name");
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo $result['name'] . 
   "(<a href='users.php?action=edit&id={$result['id']}'>edit</a>) " .
   "(<a href='users.php?action=delete&id={$result['id']}'>delete</a>)<br />";
  }
 break;

 case 'edit':
  // TODO: you probably need to check for the privileges of the user who visits this edit interface.
  //       compare $id against current user's id, for example!
  $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
  if (!mysql_num_rows($query)) {
   // oops, there's no such user, stop executing the script and output an error
  }
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
  // output your user form here

  // after the user saves the form, this gets executed
  if (count($_POST)) {
   // collect user data, clean it up and save back into database
  }

 break;

 case 'delete':
  // checks for ID are the same as in 'edit', make sure the user exists. 
  // TODO: check the current user so that he/she actually could delete users
  $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = {$id}"); // assuming id as good integer.
  // output some success message
 break;
}

?>
```